# Setting TCP keepalive on a CONTAINER

Tags: linux, containers, azure-aks, sysctl, tcp-keepalive

I am using Azure Kubernetes, and trying to set TCP_Keepalive on a container basis.
Is there away of achieving that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this via sysctls on the pod manifest in AKS/Kubernetes:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: "net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time"
      value: "45"
```

Here is also further documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/

https://docs.syseleven.de/metakube/de/tutorials/confiugre-unsafe-sysctls

Comment: Thanks, I already did this. But we are using AKS and it requires enabling a BETA (Preview) feature on the cluster, which won't do in PROD. I wanted a way enabling this on the container level, Thanks for the input : )